# How to submit html form from API Nodejs + Expressjs

Tags: node.js, forms, express, zoho

I am using Express for API development, Needs to submit HTML form on calling  GET API call

I have added below code, it's working fine when its opened from the browser but when calling from Postman or Angular HTTP GET it will not submit a form.

controller code :

```
  zohoFormSubmit: async (req, res, next) => {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write('<html><body><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><form name="WebToLeads25788000000071001" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="zohoForm" action="https://**.zoho.in/crm/**"><input type="text" name="****" value="**" /><input type="hidden" name="zc_gad" id="zc_gad" value="" /><input type="text" name="xmIwtLD" value="**" /><input type="text" name="actionType" value="TGVhZHM=" /><input type="text" name="returnURL" value="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;login.sthalmatrimony.com&#x2f;" /><input type="text" name="First Name" value="MANGESH" /><input type="text" name="Last Name" value="MANGESH" /><input type="text" name="Email" value="**@gmail.com" /><input type="text" name="Mobile" value="*****" /><input type="text" name="City" value="Pune" /></form><script type="text/javascript">document.WebToLeads25788000000071001.submit();</script></body></html>');
        res.end();
    }
```

If any one came across the same scenerio please help here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `res.send("<>HTML here</>")` or `res.sendFile(<fileName>)`

see: https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#res.send

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
zohoFormSubmit: async (req, res, next) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.write('<html> <body><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><form name="WebToLeads25788000000071001" id="WebToLeads25788000000071001" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://**.zoho.in/crm/**"><input type="text" name="****" value="**" /><input type="hidden" name="zc_gad" id="zc_gad" value="" /><input type="text" name="xmIwtLD" value="**" /><input type="text" name="actionType" value="TGVhZHM=" /><input type="text" name="returnURL" value="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;login.sthalmatrimony.com&#x2f;" /><input type="text" name="First Name" value="MANGESH" /><input type="text" name="Last Name" value="MANGESH" /><input type="text" name="Email" value="**@gmail.com" /><input type="text" name="Mobile" value="*****" /><input type="text" name="City" value="Pune" /></form><script type="text/javascript">document.forms[\'WebToLeads25788000000071001\'].submit();</script></body></html>');
  res.end();
}
```

Hope its help